# how to modify 2 polygon in ol.js

Tags: javascript, split, html-lists

[step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCnU1.png)

[step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16aK8.png)

How to use ol.js to modify the walls of objects when the objects on the map are in modify mode, so that if one side is moved, the other wall on this wall of another object will be moved with it ??

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import {Circle as CircleStyle, Fill, Stroke, Style} from 'ol/style';
import {Draw, Modify, Snap} from 'ol/interaction';
import {OSM, Vector as VectorSource} from 'ol/source';
import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer';

var raster = new TileLayer({
  source: new OSM(),
});

var source = new VectorSource();
var vector = new VectorLayer({
  source: source,
  style: new Style({
    fill: new Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
    }),
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: '#ffcc33',
      width: 2,
    }),
    image: new CircleStyle({
      radius: 7,
      fill: new Fill({
        color: '#ffcc33',
      }),
    }),
  }),
});

var map = new Map({
  layers: [raster, vector],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [-11000000, 4600000],
    zoom: 4,
  }),
});

var modify = new Modify({source: source});
map.addInteraction(modify);

var draw, snap; // global so we can remove them later
var typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');

function addInteractions() {
  draw = new Draw({
    source: source,
    type: typeSelect.value,
  });
  map.addInteraction(draw);
  snap = new Snap({source: source});
  map.addInteraction(snap);
}

/**
 * Handle change event.
 */
typeSelect.onchange = function () {
  map.removeInteraction(draw);
  map.removeInteraction(snap);
  addInteractions();
};

addInteractions();
```

When in the image, if 2 polygons are joined together on the same connected side, when moving one of these common sides, both sides are moved. Where can I check the changes in this code, or where did I have a problem ??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet. See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I could not find an algorithm or I could not make it that I want to recount my algorithm here !!
The introductory code is also available on the ol.js site itself to launch just the design canvas, but I'm looking for help or a solution that I can use to get what I have in mind with this introductory code.
The only thing I have in mind are these 2 photos that I put

Comment: In this case, you should share the results of your own research. Please read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question by adding your efforts and why they do not work.

Comment: This is the result of the research and the code I have written and changed to date.
Do you have a solution to my problem ??